# Apparently missing ) gets fixed in jQuery :not(.class on all but Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I had a jQuery Syntax-Error in my Script but only Safari throw an exception.

```
$("#id:not(.class").length
```

The :not wasn't closed by ). In Safari length was 0, in all other browser it was the correct value if the error hadn't exist. Could it possible that Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer fixes these errors on the fly?

Additionally, it seems not to be inherent to jQuery, because even native `querySelector` calls recovers syntax errors in the selector literal:

```
document.querySelector('[href^="h'  ) ===
document.querySelector('[href^="h"]'); // true in non-Safari

document.querySelector(':not([X="Y'   ) ===
document.querySelector(':not([X="Y"])'); // true in non-Safari
```

Error raised in Safari reads `SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12`.

Comment: +1 I think this question is legit. Out of curiousity, I would like to know this too.

Comment: +1 Good question, disguised as a simple one.

Comment: Absolutely. This is very important for developers.

Comment: Jabaluza, I edited your question so its meaning is more obvious / no longer looks like a syntax mistake. You are welcome to make further edits.

Comment: Why would you use a not class selector with an ID anyway? As IDs must be unique, you can't have one ID with a class, and then the same ID without a class (or with a different class).

Comment: @j08691, `function handleEnterPressed() { if($('button#send:not(.disabled)').length) { // proceed to send message } }` Some times you want to use `class="disabled"` instead of attribute `disabled` on buttons, so that keyboard functions such as reload are not disabled when the button has focus and then gets disabled. CSS can be used to make the button 'look' disabled. There are other possibilities, and the question actually applies to other cases as well.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey and OP: added remark about native querySelector* (which presumably jQuery calls under the hood); I think that the jQuery label and stuff here is not necessary, but didn't dare to remove it and reword whole question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is really somehow fascinating because I have asked myself this a lot of times, too, without further investigation why that is. Chrome indeed sometimes "ignores" syntax errors, for example when you add or leave out `;` or `,` in object notations for instance.

That can be a good thing but is sometimes hard to debug. Older browsers like IE throw errors where newer browsers dont. I dont know if this is a feature or a bug :)

I dont have sources on this but I can confirm that I noticed similar behavior. Most likely this has something to do with [JavaScipt's strict mode](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/javascript-strict-mode/).

Answer (score -1):

This should be

```
  $("#id:not('.class')").length
```

instead of

```
 $("#id:not(.class").length
```

Comment: Yes, i know. But why doesn't Chrome & Co. throws an exception?

Comment: I think you need to read the question again.  He's aware of the syntax error.  The question is about why different browsers react differently.

Comment: @Archer it is depend on browser itself

Comment: @Amit so, Chrome and the other browsers fixes errors like this by itself?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the browser - exactly.  That's what the question is about, so telling him how to fix a syntax error is not relevant :)